# Действие при соприкосновении элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, хочу сделать выстрел, при клике(параллельно сделать при нажатии на кнопку, например кнопка В) на элемент(пушка, находится внизу экрана) с него вылетает, другой элемент(пуля), при соприкосновении с третьим элементом(муха, летает вверху , вправо - влево) исчезают оба(пуля и муха)... - и выстрел не один а несколько)

```js
        $('.shooter').click(function(){

            $('.shell').animate({
                'top':'-400px',
            }, 100)
        });
```

```css
        body{
            position: relative;
            background: #a9a9a9;
            margin:5% 20%;
            height:300px;
        }
        .target{
            position: absolute;
            width:10px;
            height:5px;
            top:10px;
            left:30px;
            background: #000;
        }
        .target+.target{
            left:100px;
        }
        .shooter{
            position: absolute;
            top:250px;
            left:50%;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .shooter>span{
            height:20px;
            width:4px;
            -webkit-border-radius:50%;
            -moz-border-radius:50%;
            border-radius:50%;
            background:green;
            margin: 5px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .shooter>span.gun{
            padding-bottom:10px;
        }
        .shooter>span.shell{
            background: red;
            top: -5px;
            left: 9px;
            position: absolute;
        }
        *{
            transition: .5s all linear;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="target"></div>
    <div class="shooter">
        <span class="gun"></span>
        <span class="shell"></span>
        <span class="gun"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: прошу извинить, не совсем умею вставлять код))

Comment: ничего, научитесь со временем :)

Comment: Не вполне понятно, о чём собственно спрашивается?

Comment: допустим нижнее ружье можно двигать и при попадании в верхний квадратик должен пропасть квадратик, и красненькие пульки должны быть бесконечны)

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы мы написали код за вас?

Comment: Придумал себе, и хочу сделать, в интернете не нашел примеров, надеюсь тут кто-то поможет что бы научиться...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делать было нечего, вот моя простыня. Не претендует на образец написания, но общие идеи, надеюсь, передам.
*Алсо, подписи будут чуть позже*
*Писалось под хром*
*P.S.S. доиграл до 18, хехе*

```js
String.prototype.noPx = function(){//решил написать функцию, которая поможет избавиться от мерзких `px`
//впрочем, вышло все равно костыльно, переделывать - лень
 var str = this.toString();
 if(str.substr(-2,2) === 'px'){
  return str.substr(0,str.length-2)*1;
    }
 return 0;
}

var Target = function(){//создаем класс для цели
  var self = this;//дабы удобнее было ссылаться на себя
  var direction = 1;//куда летим?
  var difficulty = document.getElementById('score').innerHTML*1;
  //небольшой модификатор сложности ;)
  this.obj = document.createElement('div');
  this.obj.setAttribute('id','target');
  document.body.appendChild(this.obj);
  setInterval(function(){
    var x = self.obj.style.left.toString().noPx();
    //x = x.noPx();
    if(x > 100){//летать будем в диапазоне (0...100)px
      direction = -1;
    }else if( x < 0){
      direction = 1;
    }
    x += (2 + difficulty) * direction;//инкрементим позицию по Х с заданным знаком
    self.obj.style.left = x + 'px';
  }, 40);
}

var Bullet = function(from){
  var self = this;
  this.obj = document.createElement('div');
  this.obj.setAttribute('class','bullet');
  this.obj.style.left = from.obj.style.left;
  
  document.body.appendChild(this.obj);
  setInterval(function(){//тут мы слушаем, что случается с нашей пулей
                         //а также, производим с ней необходимые манипуляции
    var bot = self.obj.style.bottom.noPx();
    var top = $(self.obj).position().top;
    if(top < 0){
      $(self.obj).trigger('collect');
    }
    var pos = $(self.obj).position();
    var tar = document.getElementById('target');
    if(tar){//Собственно вот тут и начинаем проверять коллизии объектов
      var tar_pos = $(tar).position();//получаем позицию цели
      if(Math.abs((pos.left+2) - (tar_pos.left+15)) < 15){
        /*(тут небольшая хитрость - точнее костыль
        в идеале, надо было бы к координатам прибавлять половины
        ширины и высоты элементов, при этом получая их центр)
        примерно найдем центр элементов, что пули, что объекта
        Далее, смотрим, если расстояние по Х между этими центрами
        меньше половины цели, то значит у нас есть попадание по Х, проверяем дальше*/
        if(Math.abs((pos.top - 7) - (tar_pos.top-5)) < 10){
          /*
          Тоже самое делаем и по Y, правда я решил немного расширить диапазон
          попадания, из-за того, что пуля может просто "перескочить" цель
          из-за большого инкремента по Y
          */
          document.body.removeChild(tar);//Удаляем сбитую цель
          var target = new Target();//тут же создаем новую, мы же азартные ребята, играем на счет, верно?
          $(document).trigger('hit');//Триггерим событие попадания
        }
      }
    }
    //console.log(top);
    bot += 20;//Тут инкрементим позицию пули по оси Y
    self.obj.style.bottom = bot + 'px';
    
  }, 50);
}

var Cannon = function(){

  var self = this;
  this.loaded = true;
  this.obj = document.createElement('div');
  this.obj.setAttribute('class','cannon loaded');
  this.fire = function(){//Стреляем
    if(self.loaded){//Только если заряжены
      self.loaded = false;
      var bullet = new Bullet(self);//Стреляем собссно пулей(забавно, да?)
      self.reload();//перезаряжаемся 
    } 
  }
  this.reload = function(){//вот таким образом
    self.obj.classList.remove('loaded');
    setTimeout(function(){
      self.loaded = true;
      self.obj.classList.add('loaded');
    }, 1000);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(this.obj);//прикручиваем пушку к документу
  self.obj.addEventListener('click', self.fire, false);//следим за тем, когда нажмут на курок
  $(document).on('collect', '.bullet', function(){//собираем пульки, улетевшие за горизонт
    $(this).remove();
  });
  $(document).on('hit', function(){//а тут увеличиваем счетчик, для удовлетворения нашего самолюбюия
    var score = $('#score').text();
    $('#score').text(++score);
  })
}
var tar = new Target();//Создаем пушку
var can = new Cannon();//Создаем цель
```

```css
#target{
  display: block-inline;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
#score_wrap{
  float: right;
}
.cannon{
  display: block-inline;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.cannon.loaded{
  border-bottom: 10px solid green;
}
.bullet{
  display: block-inline;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="score_wrap">Score <span id='score'>0</span></span>
```

---

Более детальные объяснения(*многие из которых - личное мнение*):
Итак, во-первых, для меня такие вещи легче и разумнее делать через Объекты, в нашем случае это:

```
var Target = function(){//Здесь, Target - имя своеобразного класса в JS
    this.param = ...//А здесь мы перечисляем его свойства и методы
                    //т.е. то, что он имеет в себе, и что умеет делать
    ...
}
```

Делается это для того, чтобы сделать сущности(объекты) более самостоятельными, закладывая всю логику их работы в них самих же, а не устраивая хитросплетения функций между ними. Так же удобно обращаться к их свойствам и методам, можно создавать несколько экземпляров одного и того же объекта(как например, мы создаем пули и цели) и все они будут вести себя идентично, что в нашем случае также удобно.
    Продолжая основную идею, внутри каждого объекта(его функции), мы задаем скажем так, *Главную функцию*, которая и будет выполнять все основные действия с нашим объектом. Но, так, как нам необходимо производить эти действия *во времени*, мы эту функцию объявили через `setInterval(функция, промежуток_в_мс)`.
    Таким образом, наша функция выполняется с определенной периодичностью, наблюдая за тем, пересекаются ли объекты, какие у кого координаты, и так далее. При этом, чем *меньше* промежуток, тем "плавнее" будут изменения на экране(но при этом и быстрее), однако, это приведет к повышению ресурсоемкости скрипта. Поэтому, не каждой такой функции нужно задавать минимальные промежутки выполнения.

Comment: А где лидерборд? Как мериться-то?

Comment: @vp_arth, джентльмены верят на слово! мериться можете в комментах)

Comment: все супер, хотелось бы что бы пулька при столкновении исчезала, но это не так)) да и цель исчезать должна, или это легка исправимо? просьба больше  комментариев, мне еще учится и учится...

Comment: как убрать цель при попадании нашел)) вот только заметил что пульки улетевшие за горизонт не собираются  $('div').on('collect', function(){            $(this).remove();, походу что-то пошло не так(

Comment: @Ivan, добавлю более подробные комменты позже, исправил улетание за горизонт, заметил только вчера вечером `=)`

Comment: Нужно еще повышать скорость пули, а то после 25-го уровня слишком быстро можно дойти до 50-го.

Comment: да пуля уже не улетает, круто)) я удалял  var target = new Target(); и вместо писал анимацию на 5сек, и через 5сек, цель у меня исчезала setTimeout(function(){$('#target').fadeOut('fast')},5000); как впрочем я и хотел))) но left в цели продолжал меняться...

Comment: @Ivan, потому что нужно в `callback'e` у `fadeOut` написать, чтобы он удалил сам элемент: `fadeOut('fast',function(){$('#target').remove()})`

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, думал про это. Вообще, много про что думал, для усложнения, но в итоге подумал, что на работе надо бы поработать, а это дома допилить `:D`

Comment: а сделать цели 77 жизней и урон пульке от 10 до 15, и сделать что бы шкала жизней цели была видна в процентах))) или это уже перебор?